# Value of type 'some UIView' has no member 'scrollView'

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I'm trying to load a youtube video in my app in swift ui

Tutorial I'm following writes the following code

```
uiView.scrollView.isScrollEnabled = false
uiView. load(URLRequest(url: YouTubeURL))
```

In my case, I get the following error
**Value of type 'some UIView' has no member 'scrollView'**

That's the whole struct if it helps

```
struct Video: UIViewRepresentable {
    let videoId: String?
    
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> some UIView {
        return WKWebView()
    }
    
    func updateUIView(_ uiView: UIViewType, context: Context) {
        guard let ytId = videoId else { return }
        let ytUrl = URL(string: baseUrl + ytId)
        
        uiView.scrollView
        uiView.load
        
    }
}
```

Any idea how to fix that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably accepted the auto-completion for this line based on implementing the [UIViewRepresentable](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/uiviewrepresentable) protocol:

```
func makeUIView(context: Context) -> some UIView {
```

This says that the result is "some kind of UIView, but the caller doesn't know what kind." As part of this protocol, it also sets UIViewType to be `some UIView`. You can't then use WKWebView-specific properties on that. What you very likely meant to write here was:

```
func makeUIView(context: Context) -> WKWebView {
```

You likely also want to change this line to use WKWebView explicitly, in order to be a bit clearer:

```
func updateUIView(_ uiView: WKWebView, context: Context) {
```